# value "ID" for the selected row is not parsing on AJAX JQUERY

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an HTML table where the data was retrieved from a database using PHP hence I used a loop to echo the rows. Which created my initial problem of trying to retrieve the correct ID using AJAX. I was recommended using class to create my JQUERY Code I don't knoe what I am doing wrong.

My objective:
I am trying to parse the selected row's ID into my jquery code which then parses into a second php script.

This is my code of the HTML table:

```
<form id="mainform" >
    <table id="table1">
        <?php
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM test");
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                $ID = $row['ID'];
                echo "<tr data-rows='$ID'><td>$ID</td>";
                echo "<td><input type='hidden' class='hf' value='$ID' /></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='button' class='abc' value='select' /></td></tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </table>
</form>
```

This is my JAVASCRIPT code:

```
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $(".abc").each(function(){
            var btn = $(this);

            btn.on("click",function(){
                $("#newdiv").empty();
                var rowId = $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-row');
                $('.hf').each(function(){
                        $.get("boom.php", { ID: rowId } ,function(data) {
                        $("#newdiv").append(data);
                    });
                });
            });
        });
   });
</script>
```

I don't know where I went wrong?

I edted the CODE to my latest version

Comment: And all boom.php is does is echos the parsed variable which is in turn returned to #newdiv by jquery

Comment: Can you please show the generated HTML and explain what is supposed to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert this line

```
echo "<tr><td>".$ID."</td></tr>";
```

To this:

```
echo "<tr data-row='$ID'><td>$ID</td>";
```

Then, in your javascript, use the power of jQuery to find that attribute in your onClick handler.

```
btn.on("click",function() {
    var rowId = $(this).closest('<tr>').attr('data-row');
}
```

The variable rowId should now match which row you are on. From there you can pass that in your AJAX calls.

EDIT: You also have mismatched selectors on your jQuery each() function. You have

```
$("#abc").each(function(){
}
```

But in the HTML, the button has no ID selector, only a class. Change that line to this:

```
$('.abc').each(function () {
}
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for your help but now I get this error : Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <tr>. I have also added the msising </tr>

Comment: Make sure there is a " at the end of the <tr data=row> line. echo "<tr data-row='$ID'><td>$ID</td></tr>";

Comment: Thanks , I just changed that but it still gives the same error...

Comment: In your code you don't close the </tr>. Add that to the last echo line. Can you post your error message?

Comment: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: <tr>   that's all it says looking from console on Chrome. Any advice on how I can find more detail answers , it would be great

Comment: Update your quest with the new code. You are missing a " or something somewhere

Comment: Hello there, I just updated the code am I in the right direction?

Comment: oh gods I'm sorry. Change $(this).closest('<tr>'.attr('data-row') to $(this).closest('tr').attr('data-row)

Comment: Thank you so much there is no longer any error but I don't think the value is being parsed properly now boom.php is not echoning the value out :S.

Comment: Update your javascript code

Comment: Yup, I am confused why the value is not parsing. Anways  thanks for all your help.

Comment: Ok I see...its the javascript...thanks